# How to make a section permanently visible in a CDF while scrolling to other sections

Tags: front-end, cdf-format

Suppose I have many sections on the CDF, and I would like to alway keep section 1 visible on the CDF even though I scroll down to other section (says section 20). Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Can you do it in a notebook?

Comment: Look into [`DockedCells`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DockedCells.html)

Comment: By section you mean a cell or a cell group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you use DockedCells as suggested by Carl Woll, or you do something like this:

```
SystemOpen[CDFDeploy["test.cdf", 
   Column[{TextCell["This is the first section, permanent", "Section"], DateString[], 
     Pane[DocumentNotebook[Flatten[Table[{TextCell[StringJoin["Section ", 
            ToString[i]], "Section"], ExpressionCell[i^2]}, {i, 2, 10}]]], 
      ImageSize -> {500, 300}, Scrollbars -> True]}], Method -> "Standalone"]]
```

[image]